# Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 - Visual Studio Core Features Fatal error during installation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, package, failed-installation

I tried installing MS Visual studio 2012 but it always gives the same error every time. I have attached the screenshot and the log file as well. Please any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Error Screenshot:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hdl4sjmhxoojuar/Error.jpg

Log file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fraz5dhmyvy2q8w/dd_vs_ultimate_20140423033705.log

Comment: Looks to be a typical MS raft of potential reasons. Found this don't know if it will help you though. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/185ed84e-57c8-48b4-bd47-8055e788cdd0/error-installing-vs-2012-premium-a-microsoft-visual-studio-c-2012-compilers-package-failed?forum=vssetup

Comment: From looking up MSI error code 2902 (in your log), I'd guess it's an installer bug.

Comment: I had this problem, when I tried to uninstall Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 0):

I had this error. Turn off antivirus and clear out as many files as you can from the %temp% directory. Worked for me.